Finding constant for asymptotic equality
I have the following task and I'd like you to check my thoughts on it:
Is there a constant C such that when $n \to \infty$ it is true that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n} = (C + o(1))^n$
If such constant C exists, find it.
Here is my attempt so far: we know that if there is $C > 1$ such that $f(n)$ function can be written as $f(n) = (C + o(1))^n$ then it is equivalent to saying $\ln(f(n)) \sim n \ln(C)$
So I've taken ln from the left side and got $n\ln(2) - n\ln(n)$ but I can not get $n \ln(C)$ from here. Does it mean that such constant $C$ does not exist?

Use Stirling's formula.

@geetha290krm, I've tried to do it and I got: $\sqrt{2} \cdot 2^{2n}e^{-2n}n^{n}$. I guess we get nothing from here

What is the $n-$th root of what you got?

@geetha290krm, okay, I was wrong. I've used your advice and extracted n-th root from both sides, then by Stirling's formula I got that the limit of left part is $\frac{4}{e}$. Wolfram Alpha confirms it. Now please could you explain to me, is C = $\frac{4}{e}$? I guess I do not understand the notation really well. If I found out that the limit of left part is $\frac{4}{e}$, what can I say about C?

Stirling's formula gives $$
\frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!n^n }} \sim \sqrt 2 \left( {\frac{4}{{\rm e}}} \right)^n .
$$

@Gary, am I right in assuming that now we need to extract the n-th root from the right part, so the final answer is $\frac4e$?

DiscreteAsymptotic[((2 n)!/(n!*n^n))^(1/n), n -> Infinity, 
 SeriesTermGoal -> 5]

$$
\text{When } n\rightarrow \infty, \quad
\frac{\left(\frac{(2 n)!}{n!}\right)^{1/n}}{n}
\sim
+\frac{4}{e}
+\frac{2 \log (2)}{e n}
+\frac{3 \log ^2(2)-1}{6 e n^2}
+\frac{\log ^3(2)-\log (2)}{12 e n^3}
+\frac{19+15 \log ^4(2)-30 \log ^2(2)}{1440 e n^4}
+\frac{3 \log ^5(2)-10 \log ^3(2)+19 \log (2)}{2880 e n^5}
$$
 
 

PREVIOUS ANSWER:
Clear["Global`*"];
res = ((2 n)!/(n!*n^n))^(1/n) // 
  FullSimplify[#, {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}] &

$$
\frac{\left(\frac{(2 n)!}{n!}\right)^{1/n}}{n}
$$
res2 = Asymptotic[res, {n, Infinity, 7}]
res2 // FullSimplify // Expand
Limit[res2, n -> Infinity]

$$
\left [
\frac{1}{3444525} \cdot (68168266699\ 2^{2 n-\frac{49}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-7}+505078953\ 2^{2 n-\frac{43}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-6}-692337105\ 2^{2 n-\frac{35}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-5}-11416545\ 2^{2 n-\frac{29}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-4}+8530515\ 2^{2 n-\frac{19}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-3}+382725\ 2^{2 n-\frac{13}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-2}-1148175\ 2^{2 n-\frac{5}{2}} e^{-n} n^{-1}+3444525\ 2^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n}  )
\right ] ^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
$$
\frac{4}{e}
$$

Your answers are not particularly insightful. Anyone can input codes into their favorite computer algebra system and obtain a result. What is the rigorous mathematical derivation of these expasions? That is the interesting bit.
